# How to send push notification from a web app to an android app?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I have a simple android application that is receiving the push notification from firebase's console properly.
How can I send a notification from my own web application, instead of sending from firebase console?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [google firebase apis](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message) .

Comment: this should be posted as a comment rather answer. Your link may answer the question but adding some information may be a good idea

Comment: thanks @AbdulWaheed. But i am new to StackOverFlow answering, i don't have enough reputation to make comments yet.

Comment: I would like to have a sample code written in javascript using firebase to send a push notification that will be handled by an android app.